# Игра слов -- название

Tags: лексика, названия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я потерялся в поисках.
Как называется такой языковой приём? (См. картинку.)

Или фраза "несу чушь" в контексте переноса вещи. Должно ведь быть название этому приему. Слышал, что даже есть такое заболевание (искать во фразах двойной смысл).

Я думал об омонимичном софизме, но не уверен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во множестве текстов обходятся без какого-либо термина и говорят о "**буквальном прочтении метафоры**", намеренном или в силу обстоятельств, склоняющих к ошибке (в области переводов с других языков такая ошибка именуется **буквализмом**). Намеренно такое можно сделать в шутку, подобрав метафору к ситуации, в которой для внимательного реципиента она оказывается комически двусмысленной, но сама речь от этого не меняется (в отличие от случая применения *каламбура*, приёма, в котором двусмысленность возникает от сопоставления смысла слов внутри текста, а не слов с реальной ситуацией). Поэтому, если искомый термин и существует, то разве что в области способов пошутить, поскольку он не может обозначать чисто литературный приём.

Comment: Спасибо. Это не тоьько в контексте метафоры справедливо? Например, если взять фразу "оставаться на линии" - в контексте телефонного разговора, но рассматривать ее как местонахождение кого-то на линии, нарисованной на земле.